# How can I use an Ajax call in my MVC3 controller and have it call just one method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have the following in my view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Refresh", "refresh",
    new AjaxOptions { 
        UpdateTargetId = "status",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnBegin = "hide",
        OnComplete = "show",
    }
    ))
{
    <input type="submit" name="refresh" value="transfer1"/><br />
    <input type="submit" name="refresh" value="transfer2"/><br />
    <input type="submit" name="refresh" value="transfer3"/><br />
}
```

I would like to be able to have this trigger some code in my controller and keep everything in the ONE method. Within this method I want to check the value passed and do something depending which value.

This is important as I actually have many lines of input buttons. I am not sure how to do this in ONE method. Any suggestions/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by *ONE method*. Doesn't this submit the form to the `Refresh` action on the `Refresh` controller which is one method?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I want to keep everything inside the Refresh action.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem then?

Comment: Hello, Well I don't know what the action method should look like. Sorry for this but I'm very new to MVC. How can I get the value of the input when I'm inside the action method?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of the button in the controller action you could do the following:

```
public ActionResult Refresh(string refresh)
{
    if (refresh == "transfer1")
    {
        // Button 1 was clicked ...
    } 
    else if (refresh == "transfer2") 
    {
        // Button 2 was clicked ...
    }
    else if (refresh == "transfer3") 
    {
        // Button 3 was clicked ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Another possibility is to actually provide those buttons different names if you don't want to rely on testing the value of the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="refresh1" value="transfer1"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="refresh2" value="transfer2"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="refresh3" value="transfer3"/><br />
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Refresh()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["refresh1"]))
    {
        // Button 1 was clicked ...
    } 
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["refresh2"])) 
    {
        // Button 2 was clicked ...
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["refresh3"])) 
    {
        // Button 3 was clicked ...
    }
    ...
}
```